# Styled text in vue interpolation

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Is there a way to make interpolated text like this:

```
<div>{{htmlReturningFn()}}</div>
```

Then:

```
methods: {
  htmlReturningFn () {
    return `there are <strong>BOLD</strong> words in this text`
  }
}
```

Of course, the hope is to see, this:

> there are **BOLD** words in this text.

I know I can style different parts within the template, but the text I'd like to style is long, and the words that need bolding are unpredictable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can by using `v-html` directive and a `computed` property.

Like this :

**HTML**

```
<div v-html="htmlReturningFn"></div>
```

**JS**

```
computed: {
  htmlReturningFn: function ()  {
    return `there are <strong>BOLD</strong> words in this text`
  }
}
```

[VueJS Doc about raw html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

---

***Security advice :*** If your users have the possibility to modify what's in `htmlReturningFn`, it's not recommended to use it, due to possible Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) issues.